# Warning: ldap_search(): Search: Bad search filter

Tags: php

I am trying to create a login page using PHP.

Goals: 
1. The user is able to sign in using the same username/password he uses when logging into Windows 
2. The user will be redirected to a page depending on the group he belongs to

So the 1st goal is solved. The problem now is the 2nd goal.

I get an error when I run the script:

```
Warning: ldap_search(): Search: Bad search filter
```

Script:

```
$ldap['user'] = "domain\user123";
$ldap['pass'] = "password123";
$ldap['host']   = 'site.domain.com';
$ldap['port']   = 389;
$ldap['dn'] = "DC=site, DC=domain, DC=com";
$ldap_user_group = "User";
$ldap_manager_group = "Admin";

$ldap['conn'] = ldap_connect( $ldap['host'], $ldap['port'] )
or die("Could not connect to {$ldap['host']}" );

$ldap['bind'] = ldap_bind($ldap['conn'], $ldap['user'], $ldap['pass']);

if( !$ldap['bind'] )
  {
    echo "Login Failed";
  }

else if( $ldap['bind'] )
  {
    $filter = "(sAMAccountName=" . $ldap['user'] . ")";
    $attr = array("memberof");
    $result = ldap_search($ldap['conn'],$ldap['dn'], $filter, $attr)
    or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap['conn'], $result);
    ldap_unbind($ldap);

    foreach($entries[0]['memberof'] as $grps) 
       {
         if (strpos($grps, $ldap_manager_group)) 
            { 
               //redirect to Admin page
            }

         if (strpos($grps, $ldap_user_group)) 
            { 
               //redirect to User page
            }
}
```

I'm really lost as I have no idea what must be causing this error.

Comment: without this `$ldap['conn']` use `$conn`

Comment: Hi @Abdulla! Thanks! but it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a bad search filter as you are passing in a slash into the filter.  You are using `$ldap['user'] = "domain\user123";` in your filter here `$filter = "(sAMAccountName=" . $ldap['user'] . ")";`

Depending on your AD setup, you'll probably want to use something like `$filter = "(sAMAccountName=user123)";`

Comment: Hi @mongjong! thanks for you reply! Sorry, but does this mean I can't use domain\user123? I am only able to login like this.

Comment: You can do it a number of ways, for example, you could store the username in a different variable $ldap['username'] = "user123" then your filter can be $filter = "(sAMAccountName=" . $ldap['username'] . ")";

Comment: oh! isn't that same as my code? you mentioned about the slash. what do you suggest I do with the slash?

Comment: No it is not the same because in your code you are using $ldap['user'] = "domain\user123".  You need the domain and slash in order to bind but the domain and slash will cause issues in your filter.  So one suggestion to avoid this issue is to use another variable $ldap['username'] = "user123" as well and then use that in your filter rater than $ldap['user'].

Comment: oh ok...i got it! thanks a lot! i get a different error now. i will try to fix it and if i'm not able to do so, i will post a new one.thank you!

Comment: Glad i could help.  Good luck :)